# Backrefs not working when creating a pdf using bookdown/latex

Tags: r, pdf, bookdown, hyperref

I'm writing a latex/PDF book with [R/bookdown](https://bookdown.org/). I'm trying to include, in the bibliography, a list of the pages that each article was cited in (i.e., backrefs). However, the `backref` and `pagebackref` options of the `hyperref` latex package are not working for me for the PDF output.

Here's the code I include in the preamble to try to include backrefs:

```
\usepackage[pagebackref=true]{hyperref}
```

However, this does not create a list of "pages cited in" next to the articles in my bibliography. I am using the [`apa.csl`](https://www.zotero.org/styles/apa) Citation Style Language and the `krantz2` document class ([`krantz.cls`](https://github.com/yihui/bookdown-crc/blob/master/krantz.cls)).

Here are the contents of the `.tex` file that is generated:

```
% Options for packages loaded elsewhere
\PassOptionsToPackage{unicode}{hyperref}
\PassOptionsToPackage{hyphens}{url}
%
\documentclass[
  krantz2]{krantz}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{iftex}
\ifPDFTeX
  \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
  \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
  \usepackage{textcomp} % provide euro and other symbols
\else % if luatex or xetex
  \usepackage{unicode-math}
  \defaultfontfeatures{Scale=MatchLowercase}
  \defaultfontfeatures[\rmfamily]{Ligatures=TeX,Scale=1}
\fi
% Use upquote if available, for straight quotes in verbatim environments
\IfFileExists{upquote.sty}{\usepackage{upquote}}{}
\IfFileExists{microtype.sty}{% use microtype if available
  \usepackage[]{microtype}
  \UseMicrotypeSet[protrusion]{basicmath} % disable protrusion for tt fonts
}{}
\makeatletter
\@ifundefined{KOMAClassName}{% if non-KOMA class
  \IfFileExists{parskip.sty}{%
    \usepackage{parskip}
  }{% else
    \setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
    \setlength{\parskip}{6pt plus 2pt minus 1pt}}
}{% if KOMA class
  \KOMAoptions{parskip=half}}
\makeatother
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{longtable,booktabs,array}
\usepackage{calc} % for calculating minipage widths
% Correct order of tables after \paragraph or \subparagraph
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd\longtable{\par}{\if@noskipsec\mbox{}\fi\par}{}{}
\makeatother
% Allow footnotes in longtable head/foot
\IfFileExists{footnotehyper.sty}{\usepackage{footnotehyper}}{\usepackage{footnote}}
\makesavenoteenv{longtable}
\setlength{\emergencystretch}{3em} % prevent overfull lines
\providecommand{\tightlist}{%
  \setlength{\itemsep}{0pt}\setlength{\parskip}{0pt}}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}
\newlength{\cslhangindent}
\setlength{\cslhangindent}{1.5em}
\newlength{\csllabelwidth}
\setlength{\csllabelwidth}{3em}
\newlength{\cslentryspacingunit} % times entry-spacing
\setlength{\cslentryspacingunit}{\parskip}
\newenvironment{CSLReferences}[2] % #1 hanging-ident, #2 entry spacing
 {% don't indent paragraphs
  \setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
  % turn on hanging indent if param 1 is 1
  \ifodd #1
  \let\oldpar\par
  \def\par{\hangindent=\cslhangindent\oldpar}
  \fi
  % set entry spacing
  \setlength{\parskip}{#2\cslentryspacingunit}
 }%
 {}
\usepackage{calc}
\newcommand{\CSLBlock}[1]{#1\hfill\break}
\newcommand{\CSLLeftMargin}[1]{\parbox[t]{\csllabelwidth}{#1}}
\newcommand{\CSLRightInline}[1]{\parbox[t]{\linewidth - \csllabelwidth}{#1}\break}
\newcommand{\CSLIndent}[1]{\hspace{\cslhangindent}#1}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage[bf,singlelinecheck=off]{caption}
\captionsetup[table]{labelsep=space}
\captionsetup[figure]{labelsep=space}
\usepackage[scale=.8]{sourcecodepro}

\usepackage{framed,color}
\definecolor{shadecolor}{RGB}{248,248,248}

\renewcommand{\textfraction}{0.05}
\renewcommand{\topfraction}{0.8}
\renewcommand{\bottomfraction}{0.8}
\renewcommand{\floatpagefraction}{0.75}

\renewenvironment{quote}{\begin{VF}}{\end{VF}}
\usepackage[pagebackref=true]{hyperref}
\let\oldhref\href
\renewcommand{\href}[2]{#2\footnote{\url{#1}}}

\makeatletter
\newenvironment{kframe}{%
\medskip{}
\setlength{\fboxsep}{.8em}
 \def\at@end@of@kframe{}%
 \ifinner\ifhmode%
  \def\at@end@of@kframe{\end{minipage}}%
  \begin{minipage}{\columnwidth}%
 \fi\fi%
 \def\FrameCommand##1{\hskip\@totalleftmargin \hskip-\fboxsep
 \colorbox{shadecolor}{##1}\hskip-\fboxsep
     % There is no \\@totalrightmargin, so:
     \hskip-\linewidth \hskip-\@totalleftmargin \hskip\columnwidth}%
 \MakeFramed {\advance\hsize-\width
   \@totalleftmargin\z@ \linewidth\hsize
   \@setminipage}}%
 {\par\unskip\endMakeFramed%
 \at@end@of@kframe}
\makeatother

\makeatletter
\@ifundefined{Shaded}{
}{\renewenvironment{Shaded}{\begin{kframe}}{\end{kframe}}}
\makeatother

\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex

% to create a "see also" that appears at the bottom of the
% subentries and with no page number, do the following:
% \index{Main entry!zzzzz@\igobble|seealso{Other item}}

\newcommand{\ii}[1]{{\it #1}}
\newcommand{\nn}[1]{#1n}

\def\igobble#1{}

\urlstyle{tt}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\makeatletter
\def\thm@space@setup{%
  \thm@preskip=8pt plus 2pt minus 4pt
  \thm@postskip=\thm@preskip
}
\makeatother

\frontmatter
\ifLuaTeX
  \usepackage{selnolig}  % disable illegal ligatures
\fi
\IfFileExists{bookmark.sty}{\usepackage{bookmark}}{\usepackage{hyperref}}
\IfFileExists{xurl.sty}{\usepackage{xurl}}{} % add URL line breaks if available
\urlstyle{same} % disable monospaced font for URLs
\hypersetup{
  pdftitle={Book Title},
  pdfauthor={Author Name},
  hidelinks,
  pdfcreator={LaTeX via pandoc}}

\title{Book Title}
\author{Author Name}
\date{2023-08-16}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\thispagestyle{empty}

\begin{center}
INSERT DEDICATION
\end{center}

\setlength{\abovedisplayskip}{-5pt}
\setlength{\abovedisplayshortskip}{-5pt}

{
\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}
\tableofcontents
}
\hypertarget{preface}{%
\chapter*{Preface}\label{preface}}


INSERT TEXT HERE (Xie, 2022).

\hypertarget{references}{%
\chapter*{References}\label{references}}


\hypertarget{refs}{}
\begin{CSLReferences}{1}{0}
\leavevmode\vadjust pre{\hypertarget{ref-R-bookdown}{}}%
Xie, Y. (2022). \emph{{bookdown}: Authoring books and technical documents with {R} {Markdown}}. \url{https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=bookdown}

\end{CSLReferences}

\backmatter
\printindex

\end{document}
```

Here is the minimal reproducible example (along with [`apa.csl`](https://www.zotero.org/styles/apa) and [`krantz.cls`](https://github.com/yihui/bookdown-crc/blob/master/krantz.cls)—I'm not sure how to make those two files "minimal") that generates the above `.tex` file:

`index.rmd`:

```yaml
---
title: "Book Title"
author: "Author Name"
date: "`r Sys.Date()`"
documentclass: krantz
classoption: krantz2
bibliography: [book.bib]
site: bookdown::bookdown_site
---
```

`01-Preface.rmd`:

```
# Preface {-}

INSERT TEXT HERE [@R-bookdown].
```

`preamble.tex`:

```
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage[bf,singlelinecheck=off]{caption}
\captionsetup[table]{labelsep=space}
\captionsetup[figure]{labelsep=space}
\usepackage[scale=.8]{sourcecodepro}

\usepackage{framed,color}
\definecolor{shadecolor}{RGB}{248,248,248}

\renewcommand{\textfraction}{0.05}
\renewcommand{\topfraction}{0.8}
\renewcommand{\bottomfraction}{0.8}
\renewcommand{\floatpagefraction}{0.75}

\renewenvironment{quote}{\begin{VF}}{\end{VF}}
\usepackage[pagebackref=true]{hyperref}
\let\oldhref\href
\renewcommand{\href}[2]{#2\footnote{\url{#1}}}

\makeatletter
\newenvironment{kframe}{%
\medskip{}
\setlength{\fboxsep}{.8em}
 \def\at@end@of@kframe{}%
 \ifinner\ifhmode%
  \def\at@end@of@kframe{\end{minipage}}%
  \begin{minipage}{\columnwidth}%
 \fi\fi%
 \def\FrameCommand##1{\hskip\@totalleftmargin \hskip-\fboxsep
 \colorbox{shadecolor}{##1}\hskip-\fboxsep
     % There is no \\@totalrightmargin, so:
     \hskip-\linewidth \hskip-\@totalleftmargin \hskip\columnwidth}%
 \MakeFramed {\advance\hsize-\width
   \@totalleftmargin\z@ \linewidth\hsize
   \@setminipage}}%
 {\par\unskip\endMakeFramed%
 \at@end@of@kframe}
\makeatother

\makeatletter
\@ifundefined{Shaded}{
}{\renewenvironment{Shaded}{\begin{kframe}}{\end{kframe}}}
\makeatother

\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex

\newcommand{\ii}[1]{{\it #1}}
\newcommand{\nn}[1]{#1n}

\def\igobble#1{}

\urlstyle{tt}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\makeatletter
\def\thm@space@setup{%
  \thm@preskip=8pt plus 2pt minus 4pt
  \thm@postskip=\thm@preskip
}
\makeatother

\frontmatter
```

`after_body.tex`:

```
\backmatter
\printindex
```

`book.bib`:

```
@Manual{R-bookdown,
  title  = {{bookdown}: Authoring books and technical documents with {R} {Markdown}},
  author = {Yihui Xie},
  note   = {R package version 0.26},
  year   = {2022},
  url    = {https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=bookdown},
}
```

`_output.yml`:

```
bookdown::pdf_book:
  includes:
    in_header: latex/preamble.tex
    after_body: latex/after_body.tex
  keep_tex: true
  dev: "cairo_pdf"
  latex_engine: xelatex
  citation_package: none
  template: null
  pandoc_args: [ "--csl", "apa.csl", "--top-level-division=chapter" ]
  toc_depth: 2
  toc_unnumbered: false
  toc_appendix: true
  quote_footer: ["\\VA{", "}{}"]
  highlight_bw: true
```

If you want to see the full, working reproducible example, see here:
https://github.com/isaactpetersen/mre

You can see the output pdf of the minimal reproducible example in the GitHub Actions workflow of the repo (click on the most recent workflow run and click `_book` to download the artifact that includes the PDF):
https://github.com/isaactpetersen/mre/actions

Comment: I added a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: Honestly, I'm not totally sure about my answer, but give it a try. Your workflow uses `pandoc` with a `.csl` citation style to produce the output (`pandoc_args: [ "--csl", "apa.csl"`). But when converting from *md* through *Latex* to *PDF*, `pandoc` ususally produces no `bibitem` in the Latex file but bib entries in plain text. The `hyperref` manual says that `backref` option, as well as `pagebackref`, is working with `bibitems`. Maybe the package just can't find these and therefore produces no refs.

Comment: Sorry but I refuse to assemble all your snippets and then to run some complicated only to produce a latex file one can debug or to wander through some github artifacts. If you want help you need to show the latex file that is actually compiled by latex *here*.

Comment: I totally agree with @UlrikeFischer. Since your `_output.yml` contains the line `keep_tex: true`, it should be no problem to take that `tex` file and strip it of any unnecessary content to post it here as MWE.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion; I posted the contents of the `tex` file. @lukeflo, I'm not seeing your answer (apart from your comment above). It does seem that `pandoc` is producing bib entries in plain text (and no `bibitem` in the Latex file). Is there a way to add page backrefs to these or some other workaround that would work with my bookdown workflow?

Comment: Hello @itpetersen I regret to inform you that i don't see a single compilable latex file. Can you please provide that by editing your post?

Comment: @itpetersen, sorry, my comment was misleading. With "answer" I meant "comment".

Comment: My first idea is, compiling pandoc with `biblatex` and `-t latex` option and without `.csl` style. This will result in a `tex` file which contains correct latex `cite` commands. Then, in a second step, compile the `tex` file with e.g. `pdflatex`, `biber` and the correct `biblatex` options. But as already mentioned by the other commentators your code is much to complex to do all this steps by myself. You should do the preparation work and post only the resulting `tex` file here, **stripped** of all unnecessary packages and other stuff.

Comment: I appreciate this sentiment. I am writing this in bookdown (not `tex`), and I originally posted this on StackOverflow because I thought the R/bookdown community would be able to help address it but it got moved to the tex community. At the moment, I'm not familiar enough with LaTeX to know what is "necessary" and what is "unnecessary" in the `.tex` file. I understand that this boiled down info would be helpful to folks to answer the question, I'm just not sure how to provide it unfortunately. I appreciate people's willingness to help where they can.

Comment: Is there a need for **R**markdown? Are you using any **R**-code inside your document which gets processed when you compile the file? Or do you use bookdown just for aesthetical reasons?

Comment: Yes, there is extensive use of R code in my actual book (not the minimal reproducible example above) that is processed via Rmarkdown/bookdown.

Comment: Ok, so if you need it, I recommend you to dig into `bookdown` and find out how to edit your `_output.yml` that it outputs a `tex` file which afterwards is processed with `biblatex` to produce correct **apa** style citations including backrefs. The needed style options etc. can be managed using the `header/praeambel.tex` file. I have no clue of `bookdown` including **R**-code (only regular `pandoc`), so no help possible from my side at this point ;)

Comment: There is already `keep_tex: true` so the tex file should be available unless the option is in wrong sessions (may it is!) or there is some other problem with syntax [https://community.rstudio.com/t/knitr-keep-tex-not-keeping-the-tex-file/17549 ].  Unfortunately I was not able to download the artefacts from github.

Comment: Yes, the `tex` file is there, but with plain text references. Therefore, the OP needs to run `pandoc` with `biblatex` option to create a TeX file with correct `cite` commands which then can be processed properly using `biblatex` with `backrefs`

Comment: Yes, you was probably saying what is in the TeX file, I forgot, my appologies. OK, now the `citation_package: biblatex` should changes this thing, according to the manuals.

Answer (score 1):

So here's my answer. But, as said in the comments multiple times, your code and the workflow is too long to run all commands and debbug the output by myself.

As your using a `csl` style with pandoc there will be no `bibitems` produced which `hyperref` could use as ref point. I would recommend to run pandoc without `citeproc` and use `biblatex` option instead to output a `tex` file. Something like `pandoc <your input file> -t latex --biblatex -o xyz.tex` with the fitting files and additional arguments.

Then you can set the correct `biblatex` options, like `style=apa`, `backref` etc. and compile the `tex` file using `xelatex` and `biber`.

**Attention**: As mentioned I didn't test it for R-markdown compatibility and output due to your extensive file contents and complex workflow.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. While this might work if I were to write the `.tex` file directly, I'm not sure how to adapt this to my workflow because I run only one line in R to compile the PDF: `bookdown::render_book("index.Rmd", output_format = c("all"))`. Are you suggesting that I take the `.tex` file that is generated from that workflow (which I do have) and compile it separately myself? If so, how would you modify the input settings to make it yield the `.tex` file with whatever modifications are needed?

Comment: All of these steps/commands could easily be wrapped into a script.l, so that in the end you only have to run the script on your *rmd* file to get the PDF.

Comment: Regarding your second question. If you post a real MWE (**Minimal** Working Example) of your `tex` code, I'm sure someone here can debbug it easily and offer a fitting Latex solution

Answer (score 0):

According to this [link](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/pdf-document.html#latex-packages-for-citations), it should be possible to configure usage of latex bibliography processing, which I hope in turn could result in hyperref acting on that. This is what they say:

```
By default, citations are processed through pandoc-citeproc,
which works for all output formats. For PDF output, sometimes
it is better to use LaTeX packages to process citations, such
as natbib or biblatex. To use one of these packages, just set
the option citation_package to be natbib or biblatex, e.g.
---
output:
  pdf_document:
    citation_package: natbib
---
```

It seems to me, that of course, you have to use PDF output. I do not expect that `hyperref` would be able to modify HTML output stream for example. Even if I am wrong about that, you should at least initially refrain from `output_format = c("all"))`, switch to PDF output (see [link](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/pdf-document.html)) and use  `citation_package` similar way to the above.

If this does not lead to the results quickly, I suggest first to start with some new tiny project and exercise in that the suggestions of the manual and only after that to return to your big project. For example [here](https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/issues/2113) I see that your code `bookdown::pdf_book` most probably is already `R` code and not just a markup. Although it seems not to exclude latex biblio processing, it may be too much complex/foreign thing for most of TeX people, certainly for me it is.

The same [link](https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/issues/2113) also mentions some more complex examples that do work (or do not because of bugs) which might be useful.